# Python: how to create a csv column based on a function's parameter

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have function that write to a csv file with a set of column. Whenever I want to change some column, I have to go into my code and change it manually. How can I input the column name as a parameter and it will change the rest?

My current code:

```
def write_to_csv():
    data_writer = csv.DictWriter(open('output.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8', newline=''), fieldnames=['fund', 'Ticker', 'Price, 'Date'])
    data_writer.writeheader()
    for row in input_file:
        data_writer.writerow({'fund': fund, 'Ticker': row[0].value, 'Price': row[1].value, 'Date': row[2].value)
```

So let say, instead of changing the column `Ticker` to `Name` manually, I would like to use a parameter in the function so that: if I need the column `Ticker`, I would execute `write_to_csv(Ticker)`. If I need Name instead of ticker, I would execute `write_to_csv(Name)`.

I think the problem I am facing is to call the parameter in the quotes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's actually simpler than you're thinking.

```
def write_to_csv(column_variant='Ticker'): 
    # Use a with block so the file auto-closes
    with open('output.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8', newline='') as csv_file:
        data_writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames=['fund', column_variant, 'Price, 'Date'])     
        data_writer.writeheader() 
        for row in input_file:             
            data_writer.writerow({'fund': fund, column_variant: row[0].value, 'Price': row[1].value, 'Date': row[2].value)
```

Comment: thanks, but what if I want to use Ticker somewhere else without the quotes, i.e.. not treating it as string?

Comment: Can you elaborate please?

Comment: if I want to do some thing like : `if column = Ticker`, using your method would means `if column = 'Ticker'` which is a string

Comment: But what is the reason for wanting to do that? Doing `if column == 'Ticker'` is a perfectly acceptable and normal way.